# Which takes less memory: a Javascript array or Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

If I have a Javascript list which will have only numeric keys, which takes less memory?

```
var array = [];
array[0] = 'hello';
array[5] = 'world';
array[50] = 'foobar';

var obj = {};
obj[0] = 'hello';
obj[5] = 'world';
obj[50] = 'foobar';
```

I don't know a ton about Javascript engine internals, so...

The reason I ask is because that array, when converted to a string, will have a bunch of undefined's in the middle of it. Are those actually stored in some fashion, or is that just put in at string conversion?

Comment: To answer your last question ("Are those actually stored in some fashion?"), no, they are not stored, and yes, that is just part of the string conversion. (Although you should still use objects instead of arrays for this kind of thing.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An array is basically an ordered set of values associated with a single variable name.

In your example I think you try to do an associative array, and you should use object, Array is not meant to be used for key/value pairs.

Also the array length is indirecly increased when you assign a value to an index with higher length of the current array length:

```
var array = new Array();
array[99] = "Test";
// array.length is now 100
```

Check this [detailed article](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) on the subject.

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually increase the amount of memory the array takes up (or at least shouldn't--some browsers might not handle this kind of situation well). The `.length` property simply returns the last numerical index defined + 1, so that's why you see that behavior. But I agree that an object should be used for all reasons stated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Javascript array because you can 'only' use numeric key values, where as the object literals provide a space for key values, and even if you use numerical key values, they are probably handled differently than the numerical key values for arrays.

Most likely the *reason* arrays can't have text-based key values are because they are treated differently than object literals. I'm guessing that because they are probably treated differently, the processing for the array probably is more optimized for numeric key values, were as a object literal is optimized to use strings or numbers as their keys.

Comment: Arrays CAN have "text-based key values" ... Arrays are just objects (in JS at least).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't implement arrays like other languages so you don't get any performance enhancements inherent of a normal array (memory-wise); in JavaScript an array is very similar to an object; actually, it is essentially an object just with a few extra methods and capabilities (such as a length that updates itself). I'd say neither is quicker.

Comment: That's incorrect -- all JS implementations have "efficient" implementations of arrays, at least they are substantially more efficient than normal objects.

They all assume that a compact array is the norm, and a sparse array is uncommon, and for the reason optimise for "normal" array usage.

Very simple perf testing would have shown that :D

Comment: My **guess** is that the engine will implement an array where possible - e.g. the items can be observed as all being the same and otherwise as a hashmap similar to an object so little to no advantage there especially considering the orderable and iterable properties of an array (efficient hashmaps don't even remember insertion order, though browsers seem to have unofficially adopted insertion ordering for objects and there's definitely code in the wild that naively depends on it).