# Are JavaScript arrays associative?

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative

For instance, if I do
a[1000000]=1;
will it use memory for 1000000 elements or just for this one?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076658/javascript-array-associative-and-indexed

Comment: It seems you are asking two quite different questions here: Whether they are associative (in the title) and whether they are sparse (in the text). In fact, these two facets of JS arrays are orthogonal (i.e. the sparseness has nothing to do with associativity).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039908/does-javascript-populate-empty-array-items/

Answer (score 8):

In the ECMAScript standard (§15.4), the only special thing about array is that the `length` property is automatically updated (and a bunch of Array-specific prototype functions):

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name *P* (in the form of a String value) is an *array index* if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(`*P*`))` is equal to *P* and `ToUint32(`*P*`)` is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1.
>   ...
>   Every Array object has a `length` property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>. The value of the `length` property is numerically greater than the name of every property whose name is an array index; ...

Other than that, an Array is just an Object, which means it can be treated as an associative array, [although you shouldn't](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

---

Nowadays the JS engines should detect whether the array is dense or very sparse and switch between using a linear or associative array internally. In your case, the JS engine won't allocate a million elements.

Comment: +1 - Thank you for citing the relevant section of the spec. I'll adapt my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

**Would 1,000,000 elements be created?**

No, arrays are sparse, but their index will be persistent. *EDIT: Actually, their sparseness would be implementation-specific, but keeping them sparse in case of `a[1000000] = 1` would seem a logical thing to me.*

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var x = a[1]; // -> x := 2

delete a[1];
var y = a[1]; // -> y := undefined

a[9] = 10;
var y = a[8]; // -> z := undefined
```

**Are JS arrays associative?**

JavaScript arrays are a subset of associative arrays (in that indices have to be integers, as shown in [KennyTM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575833/are-javascript-arrays-associative/2575936#2575936). JavaScript objects are fully associative:

```
var o = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" };
var i = "key2";
var v = o[i]; // -> v := "value2"
```

Comment: Whether they're sparse or not would likely depend on the implementation. I would dare to guess that the undefined values the values inbetween get initialized to do take memory on current implementations.

Comment: I would have expected them to be sparse to save memory and time in the `var a[1000000] = x` situation. But this is very likely implementation-specific, I agree. Initializing a million `undefined` values seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: Implementing them as sparse arrays would make the common case (not having thousands of undefined values) needlessly inefficient.

Comment: @Matti: I would be interested in a definition/spec that clarifies this point. Thinking about it, one *could* interpret the fixed index->value connection as associativity.

Comment: @Matti: Oh, and while we are at it: IMHO, the "common case" is a) declaring an array by literal or b) incrementally appending to it in a loop. Either way - where would sparseness imply inefficiency here?

Comment: Arrays are Objects with string-numeric keys. Like all Object, they *are* associative. Browsers usually *also* provide an optimisation for numeric keys in an Array, but that's an internal implementation matter, not part of the language.

Comment: @bobince: Thanks for the clarification. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: An Array's length property and member functions ignore any properties of the array aside from its integer-indexed elements.  If you were to add [0], [1], and ["str"] indexes to an Array, the length would be 2 (indexes 0 and 1), and copying the array via `slice()` would give you an Array without the "str" property that you added to the original.  If you need an associative array in Javascript, you should use an Object.  There's no benefit to using Array instead, or of thinking of it as an associative array just because it appears to work as one superficially.

Comment: It would seem I have failed at remembering the spec. Please excuse my stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

You may use object literal as a kind of 'associative aray' in some cases:

```
var object = {
  "first": "1",
  "second": "2",
  "third": "3",
  "fourth": "4"
};
object.fifth = "5";
object.["sixth"] = "6";
```

But it has its limitations... There is no magic 'length' parameter and you will not have access to methods that every array has.

Answer (score 0):

JS arrays are auto-growing.  Setting a[100] to 1 on an empty array will populate the first 99 elements with "undefined".

Comment: Actually nothing gets *populated*. That's why it won't be just the first elements that'll *be undefined* (as opposed to *populated with undefined*) but all elements (except `a[100]`) will be `undefined`.

Comment: To demonstrate the difference: `a[1]=undefined`. Now `a.length===2` and `a['0']===undefined` and `a[1]===undefined`, *but* whilst `'1' in a` is `true`, `'0' in a` is `false`.