# Which saves more memory, Object initializer or Array?

Tags: javascript, memory

Suppose an object contains two fields `id` and `name`. I want to store 10000 such objects in an array. I have the following two options:

**Option 1**

```
var pairs = [];
for(var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
  pairs.push({"id": i, "name": "xxx"});
}
```

**Option 2**

```
var pairs = [];
for(var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
  pairs.push([i, "xxx"]);
}
```

Suppose storing the keys is not necessary, which option's resulting `pairs` saves more memory? Are there any better options that are even more memory efficient?

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) (basically applicable here, as well)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which takes less memory: a Javascript array or Javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247116/which-takes-less-memory-a-javascript-array-or-javascript-object)

Comment: These two code are different. The first you will have result as `[object1, object2, ...]` and the second you have `[array1, array2, ...]`.

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi I don't think it's a duplicate. The question asks for essentially sparse arrays with large gaps. The answer can be quite different, as it is *possible* that a sparse array grabs a section of memory enough to also fill the gaps. or not. It's implementation dependent. In either case, it'd be different behaviour than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just measure them.

For all examples, I changed the static `"xxx"` string to be something more real (i.e. unique per `id`).

`t1` and `t2` are yours, `t3` is my idea for an even more memory-efficient layout, [a pair of "array-of-structs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA), one for the ids, one for the names.

```
const process = require("process");

function t1() {
  var pairs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    pairs.push({ id: i, name: i.toString(36) });
  }
  return pairs;
}

function t2() {
  var pairs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    pairs.push([i, i.toString(36)]);
  }
  return pairs;
}
function t3() {
  var names = [];
  var ids = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    ids.push(i);
    names.push(i.toString(36));
  }
  return [ids, names];
}

const funcs = { t1, t2, t3 };
const func = funcs[process.argv[process.argv.length - 1]];
const m1 = process.memoryUsage();
console.log(func);
const x = func();
const m2 = process.memoryUsage();
console.log(m2.rss - m1.rss);
```

In my Node 16, this outputs:

```
$ node so-memory-test.js t1
[Function: t1]
4018176
$ node so-memory-test.js t2
[Function: t2]
4759552
$ node so-memory-test.js t3
[Function: t3]
1622016
```

which would imply the AoS structure is the slimmest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It looks that t1 and t2 do not have significant difference.

Comment: "*which would imply the AoS structure is the slimmest.*" for Node.js (well, V8) that would be normal. A dense array of integers will be stored in memory more efficiently than strings or even mixed arrays. However, that's an opimisation that V8 has. Not all environments might have it. I think FF will exhibit similar behaviour.

Comment: @RichardHu, imagine if the size of the data increase. there would be a significant difference.

Comment: @ikhvjs For 10 million items, the numbers are 1001824256 / 1230794752 / 770465792 on my machine.

Comment: @AKX `t1` is between 16-19% of `t2`. Not insignificant.

Comment: @VLAZ Of course it depends on the JS runtime too :)